# Parsing (possibly) non-existend numbers with regexp in R

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to extract numbers from strings in R with the package `stringr`. Sometimes, the numbers are not present. Here are some example strings:

```
str <- c(
"cash dividends per share $ - $ - $ - $ 0.08 $ 0.16 cash",
"cash dividends per share $ 0.01 $ 12.10 $ 0.01 $ 0.08 $ 0.16 hello",
"cash dividends per share $ - $ - $ 0.91 $ - $ 0.16 world",
"cash dividends per share - - 0.12 - 0.16 hsac",
"cash dividends per share $ - $ - $ - $ - $ 0.16 afterwards",
"cash dividends per share $0.12 $ - $0.1 $ - $ - comes",
"cash dividends per share 0.12 - 0.12 - - text",
"cash dividends per share... 0.12 - 0.12 - - random",
"cash dividends per share...0.123 0.321 - - 0.12 blu",
"cash dividends per share ..... $ 0.12 $ - $ 0.12  $ - $ - foo",
"cash dividends per share ..... $0.42 $0.42 $-  $- $- bar")
```

I built the following regular expression which IMO should match all cases, but it doesn't. Of course, I also tried various different ones, but I am not able to figure the correct one out (I am not even able to see the problem with the one I came up with):

```
library("stringr")
rgxp <- "cash dividends [declared]* per share[ \\.]+[\\$]?[ ]?([-0.9\\.]+)[ ]?[\\$]?[ ]?([-0.9\\.]+)[ ]?[\\$]?[ ]?([-0.9\\.]+)[ ]?[\\$]?[ ]?([-0.9\\.]+)[ ]?[\\$]?[ ]?([-0.9\\.]+).*"
str_match_all(str, rgxp)
```

Do you see any problem why the above regular expression fails?

**Edit:** I should have said that my desired output is *alyways* a vector with five elements, i.e., either the numbers or the hyphen if there is no number. Thanks!

Comment: What is your desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to capture the numbers and hyphens:

```
rgxp <- "([0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*)|(-)"
str_extract_all(str, rgxp)

[[1]]
[1] "-"    "-"    "-"    "0.08" "0.16"

[[2]]
[1] "0.01"  "12.10" "0.01"  "0.08"  "0.16" 

[[3]]
[1] "-"    "-"    "0.91" "-"    "0.16"

[[4]]
[1] "-"    "-"    "0.12" "-"    "0.16"

[[5]]
[1] "-"    "-"    "-"    "-"    "0.16"

[[6]]
[1] "0.12" "-"    "0.1"  "-"    "-"   

[[7]]
[1] "0.12" "-"    "0.12" "-"    "-"   

[[8]]
[1] "0.12" "-"    "0.12" "-"    "-"   

[[9]]
[1] "0.123" "0.321" "-"     "-"     "0.12" 

[[10]]
[1] "0.12" "-"    "0.12" "-"    "-"   

[[11]]
[1] "0.42" "0.42" "-"    "-"    "-"
```

If you only want the numbers:

```
rgxp <- "[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*"
str_extract_all(str, rgxp)

[[1]]
[1] "0.08" "0.16"

[[2]]
[1] "0.01"  "12.10" "0.01"  "0.08"  "0.16" 

[[3]]
[1] "0.91" "0.16"

[[4]]
[1] "0.12" "0.16"

[[5]]
[1] "0.16"

[[6]]
[1] "0.12" "0.1" 

[[7]]
[1] "0.12" "0.12"

[[8]]
[1] "0.12" "0.12"

[[9]]
[1] "0.123" "0.321" "0.12" 

[[10]]
[1] "0.12" "0.12"

[[11]]
[1] "0.42" "0.42"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It is a good solution but I would like to have the same length for each result vector. Please see my edit of the original question.

Comment: @Michael just change  to `rgxp <- "([0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*)|(-)"`, I will edit the answer.

Comment: Or `regmatches(str, gregexpr("([0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*)|(-)", str))` with base

Answer (score 3):

Use `gsub` to replace any two or more consecutive dots and any character not a minus, digit or dot with a space and then read in using `read.table`.  Omit `na.strings = "-"` if you want minus characters to appear where the NAs are.  No packages are used.

```
DF <- read.table(text = gsub("[^-0-9.]+|\\.{2,}", " ", str), fill = TRUE, na.strings = "-")
```

giving this data.frame:

```
> DF
      V1     V2   V3   V4   V5
1     NA     NA   NA 0.08 0.16
2  0.010 12.100 0.01 0.08 0.16
3     NA     NA 0.91   NA 0.16
4     NA     NA 0.12   NA 0.16
5     NA     NA   NA   NA 0.16
6  0.120     NA 0.10   NA   NA
7  0.120     NA 0.12   NA   NA
8  0.120     NA 0.12   NA   NA
9  0.123  0.321   NA   NA 0.12
10 0.120     NA 0.12   NA   NA
11 0.420  0.420   NA   NA   NA
```

**Note:** If you want to replace the NA's with zeros then use: `DF[is.na(DF)] <- 0`.

Comment: Thanks, nice solution!